# Get and put paramter to url based on slected data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a following `<div>` structure:

```
<div class="color-class" data-color="red">
   <div class="inside-color">Red</div>
</div>
<div class="color-class" data-color="green">
    <div class="inside-color">Green</div>
</div>
<div class="color-class" data-color="blue">
    <div class="inside-color">Blue</div>
</div>
```

So, when people click on any color class then the page is redirected with corresponding color in the url with the following:

```
var color=urlObj.searchParams.get("color");

$(".color-class").on("click",function(){
    if( $(this).find(".inside-color").hasClass("selected")){
        location.href=location.href.replace(/&?color=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "");
    }
    else {
        var se_val=$(this).data("color");
        $(this).find(".inside-color").addClass("selected");

        if ( !color ){
            if(url.indexOf("?") >= 0){
                url =url+"&color="+se_val;
            }
            else {
                url =url+"?color="+se_val;
            }
            window.location.href=url;
            return;
        }
        if ( color){
            urlObj.searchParams.set("color", color+","+se_val);
            window.location.href=urlObj;
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

So using this code i can redirect so after my redirection i get url like   `example.com/?color=red`

Then I have to add class name called **selected** to  the corresponding **inside-color**.

So I write the following code:

```
if ( color ){
    $(".color-class[data-color='"+color+"']").find(".inside-color").addClass("selected");
}
```

1. But if my url is **http://www.example.com/?color=red%2Cgreen** how i can add **selected** class to both…  ie add selected class to both red and green,
2. If my url is **http://www.example.com/?color=red%2Cgreen** and some one again click on green color then how can i remove green from the url and add selected to red color only.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider if this was a form, you might have something like:

```html
<form action="example.com" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" class="inside-color" name="inside-color[]" value="red" /><label>Red</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="inside-color" name="inside-color[]" value="green" /><label>Green</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="inside-color" name="inside-color[]" value="blue" /><label>Blue</label>
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

This will create an encoded URL like:

```
example.com?inside-color%5B%5D=red&inside-color%5B%5D=green
```

This is the method for passing an Array via GET. one option would be to pass the details in this method and parse it. Doing this will result in a small array and you can then iterate the array set `selected` on each of the specific colors.

In your example, you are passing a single string in one variable, and using a delimiter. Sp you'd need to first get the string and then split it. Again, this will result in an array that can be iterated.

if the user unchecked one of the options, removing `selected`, you could then remove that element from the array.

My suggestions:

```js
function setSelections(c) {
  $.each(c, function(k, v) {
    if (v) {
      $(".color-class[data-color=" + k + "]").addClass("selected");
    }
  });
}

$(function() {
  var colors = {
    red: 0,
    green: 0,
    blue: 0
  };
  $(".color-class").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
      $(this).removeClass("selected");
      colors[$(this).attr("data-color")] = 0;
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      colors[$(this).attr("data-color")] = 1;
    }
  });
  $("#save-selection").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "http://example.com/?" + $.param(colors);
    console.log("URL: " + url);
  })
});
```

```css
.color-class {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.color-class:hover {
  border-color: #a0a0a0;
}

.color-class.selected {
  border-color: #202020;
}

.color-class .inside-color {
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 75%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30%;
}

.color-class .inside-color.red {
  background: red;
}

.color-class .inside-color.green {
  background: green;
}

.color-class .inside-color.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-class" data-color="red">
  <div class="inside-color red">Red</div>
</div>
<div class="color-class" data-color="green">
  <div class="inside-color green">Green</div>
</div>
<div class="color-class" data-color="blue">
  <div class="inside-color blue">Blue</div>
</div>
<button id="save-selection">Save</button>
```

The console shows: URL: `http://example.com/?red=1&green=1&blue=0` This will be easier to parse back into an object that can be used with `setSelections()` function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it's very helpful solution . But what we do we have many inside-color ? that time i cant't set url like http://example.com/?red=1&green=1&blue=0 , because there were toomany parameter will come in the url

Answer (score 1):

ok try something  like this  i am just posting some part of your code

```
    var color=urlObj.searchParams.get("color"); 
    if ( color ){
    var splitColors = color.split('%2C');
    for(var i=0;i<splitColors.length;++i)
{
 $(".color-class[data-color='"+splitColors[i]+"']").find(".inside-color").toggleClass("selected");
} 
}
```

Comment: Good idea , actually i forgot about that . Thank you .  But if you can check the second point in my question  , then it will be very helpful to me .

Comment: ya dude thats why i used toggleClass it should do the trick if one color repeat multiple time it will automatically toggle the selec class.Check inside the for loop code

Comment: actually for second point we have to modify the action inside  if( $(this).find(".inside-color").hasClass("selected")){  }